# couldn't resolve error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FAIL_ON_SYMBOL_HASH_OVERFLOW- elasticsearch java client api

Tags: elasticsearch, glassfish-4.1, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete feature using elaticsearch 6.2.4 and its java rest client API on my maven  web application which is running under glassfish 4.1
I am facing the below error:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FAIL_ON_SYMBOL_HASH_OVERFLOW

I have read some about it and made changes accordingly essentially on project dependencies( inside pom.xml) because all responses that I met, turned around conflict on Jackson library version.

here is the code that I tried to run:

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
        RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")
                ));

         SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest( "trustiser_suggest" );
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        String[] includeFields = new String[] {"member_mname","member_pic","member_fname","member_lname","topic_label"};
        String[] excludeFields = null;
        searchSourceBuilder.fetchSource(includeFields, excludeFields);
 Map<String, List<? extends ToXContent>> contextMap = new HashMap<>();
    contextMap.put("account_state", Collections.singletonList(CategoryQueryContext.builder().setCategory("active").build()));
        SuggestionBuilder termSuggestionBuilder = SuggestBuilders.completionSuggestion("suggest_member" )
                .prefix( str )
                .contexts(contextMap);
        SuggestBuilder suggestBuilder = new SuggestBuilder();
        suggestBuilder.addSuggestion( "suggest-mem", termSuggestionBuilder );

         SuggestionBuilder termSuggestionBuilder1 = SuggestBuilders.completionSuggestion("suggest_topic" )
                .prefix( str )
                .skipDuplicates(true);
        suggestBuilder.addSuggestion( "suggest-top", termSuggestionBuilder1 );
        searchSourceBuilder.suggest( suggestBuilder);


        searchRequest.source( searchSourceBuilder );
        SearchResponse searchResponse = null;

            searchResponse = client.search( searchRequest );

        System.out.println("AutoCompleteMemberTopicccccccccccccccc: "+searchResponse.toString());
```

my curent pom.xml:

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.10</version>

</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.4</version>

</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.4</version>
</dependency>


        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

and the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FAIL_ON_SYMBOL_HASH_OVERFLOW
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContent.<clinit>(JsonXContent.java:57)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.contentBuilder(XContentFactory.java:121)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.completion.CompletionSuggestionBuilder.contexts(CompletionSuggestionBuilder.java:203)
    at com.trustiser.business.ElasticSearchDao1.AutoCompleteMemberTopic(ElasticSearchDao1.java:50)
    at com.trustiser.service.SearchEngineService.searchMemberCategory(SearchEngineService.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
```

and finally the maven tree of the web project

```
--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ elasticmavenprojet ---
com.trustiser:elasticmavenprojet:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
+- javax:javaee-web-api:jar:7.0:provided
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
+- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:6.2.4:compile
|  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-core:jar:6.2.4:compile
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:7.2.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:7.2.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:7.2.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:7.2.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:7.2.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:7.2.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:7.2.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:7.2.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:7.2.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:7.2.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:7.2.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:7.2.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial-extras:jar:7.2.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial3d:jar:7.2.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:7.2.1:compile
|  +- org.elasticsearch:securesm:jar:1.2:compile
|  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-cli:jar:6.2.4:compile
|  |  \- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.2:compile
|  +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
|  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
|  +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:jar:2.8.10:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.8.10:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.8.10:compile
|  +- com.tdunning:t-digest:jar:3.0:compile
|  +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:compile
|  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.9.1:compile
|  \- org.elasticsearch:jna:jar:4.5.1:compile
+- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:jar:6.2.4:compile
|  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
|  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.5:compile
|  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.1.2:compile
|  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.5:compile
|  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
|  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
+- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:jar:6.2.4:compile
|  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:parent-join-client:jar:6.2.4:compile
|  |  +- org.locationtech.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.6:compile
|  |  +- com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.9.1:compile
|  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:aggs-matrix-stats-client:jar:6.2.4:compile
|  \- org.elasticsearch.plugin:rank-eval-client:jar:6.2.4:compile
\- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
   \- junit:junit:jar:4.10:compile
      \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:compile
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after several days of work and research, I finally find the solution of my problem.
The problem is caused by a version conflict between dependencies of ES hight level client api and those existing on  glassfish modules ( Jackson-core is one of them).
Because replacing jars of glassfish module directory is a risky practice, the solution that I applied is to shade the ES dependency and rename there packages using maven shade plugin.
These are followed steps to implement the solution:

1. Create the shaded dependency of ES:

   - Create a java maven project;
   - The Pom.xml of the project:

```
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.trustiser</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticshade</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.4</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>

                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.elasticsearch</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>hidden.org.elasticsearch</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.apache.lucene</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>hidden.org.apache.lucene</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.fasterxml</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>hidden.com.fasterxml</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.apache.httpcomponents</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>hidden.org.apache.httpcomponents</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>

                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.hdrhistogram</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>hidden.org.hdrhistogram</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.slf4j</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>hidden.org.slf4j</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.yaml</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>hidden.org.yaml</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>net.sf.jopt-simple</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>hidden.net.sf.jopt-simple</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>joda-time</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>hidden.joda-time</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>commons-logging</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>hidden.commons-logging</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>commons-codec</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>hidden.commons-codec</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.tdunning</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>hidden.com.tdunning</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.github.spullara</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>hidden.com.github.spullara</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.carrotsearch</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>hidden.com.carrotsearch</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*:*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>                        


                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.PluginXmlResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.trustiser.elasticshade.App</mainClass>
                                </transformer>

                            </transformers>




                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
```

- Run clean, build and maven package goal;
- The jar will be created on "elastic shade project location" \target

  3. Add the shaded dependency on maven local repository:

     - Access to m2 repository from the cmd, the default location is C:\Users\"user".m2\repository , and execute the following command to istall the created dependency:   mvn install:install-file -Dfile="location of the shaded elastic dependency".jar  -DgroupId="shaded dependency groupe id" -DartifactId="shaded dependency acrifact id" -Dversion="version of the shaded dependency" -Dpackaging=jar
  4. Add the shaded dependency of elasticsearch on the pom.xml of my  maven java web application instead of using elasticsearch hight level rest api directly
  5. To avoid log4j error I add a log4j2.properties file on the resources directory of my java web app :

```
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = console
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %marker%m%n

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = console
```

Comment: I had same issue with error "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_7_3_1" and it got resolved by applying the shading on Lucene. <relocation>pattern>org.apache.lucene</pattern>shadedPattern>hidden.org.apache.lucene</shadedPattern></relocation>

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this is an error message thrown by the Jackson library which elasticsearch uses for JSON serialization and deserialization And caused by having a conflicting version of Jackson library.

I can see you are explicitly including a Jackson library by defining below dependency in your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.10</version>
</dependency>
```

And by looking at your `mvn tree`, I see elasticsearch is also bringing some Jackson libraries. Can you try below 2 options?

Option 1. Remove the explicit Jackson dependency which I just mentioned, and do a clean build. (Note this is less likely to work :), but there is no harm to try.

option 2. I looked at my project and I am using the elasticsearch 7.1 and using the below Jackson core library.
`com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.8:compile`
If you can't figure out which is the **compatible jackson core version** for your es version, then you can just upgrade to elasticsearch 7.1 and use the Jackson version I provided and it should work.

Comment: hi @Amit Khandelwal ,
thank you for your quick answer :-)
 I have already try the first option and unfortunately it dosn't work .

Comment: @AhlemTrustiser, yeah I suspected that hence mentioned its very unlikely to work :-) , can you now explore second option?

Comment: And I couldn't easly change the version of ES bacause I'm using it with neo4j, and upgrading the version means looking for a specific module to move data from database to search engine. so I will  let this option as end solution but i hope to not to do that :-\

Comment: @AhlemTrustiser, ok then you need to figure out the compatible version of Jackson core, btw did you provide your complete pom.xml ? If not can you provide that as well

Comment: hi @Amit Khandelwal,

Comment: hi let me know your question

Comment: hi @Amit Khandelwal,
the compatible version of jackson for elastic api 6.2.4 is 2.8.10.because when I don't define explicitly the jackson api on pom.xml  this is the version that is bringing by the ES api dependency.
and tis is the entire pom.xml for the project that i create to isolate the functionality to resolve the problem

Comment: seems weird, I will try creating a sample project and will share my findings

Comment: thank you so mutch, I'm wainting for your feed back!